# excel vba Change view of specific split view

Tags: excel, vba

I use a split screen (vertical) for an excel worksheet. In the left pane I want a menu with buttons (and macro). In the right pane I have named different zone of the worksheet. Clicking on a buttons should show the related zone in the right pane.
Button is working but only change the view in the left pane.

```
 Sub Vocabulaire()
   ' Vocabulaire Macro
      Application.Windows(2).ScrollColumn = 14
 End Sub
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: You've hard-coded the window index `(2)`, which may or may not be the left or right pane. Actually, `Application.Windows` might not even yield a window that belongs to the workbook you mean to work with. Use `ThisWorkbook.Windows` instead. That said I wouldn't assume anything about window count and position - users can change that faster than most code can keep up with.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer in Windows Help for VBA. It is:

```
Sub Ruban()
  With ActiveWindow.Panes(2) 'My screen is split in two vertically
   .ScrollColumn = 5 'or 60 0r 121 etc.
  End With
End Sub
```

Button menu sends Panes(2) to the fifth column. Etc.